# UnityVs Multiple Visual Studio 2015 instances

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, unityvs

I'm using Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 with Unity. The UnityVS plugin is installed. The editor configured in Unity is Visual Studio 2015.

When I open a file in Unity it opens a new Visual Studio instance. I have tried via Asset -> Open C# project, double click file, click on Open button, etc.

How do I configure Unity (or Visual Studio) to keep a single instance?

Comment: @Programmer Version 5.3.4f1 Personal

Comment: Let me know if my answer works

Comment: do what Programmer says.  One comment.  If you're using a Mac rather than PC. There's an awful lot to be said for just using BBEdit (the preferred Mac software engineer's editor).  Autocompletion is just not that important, and Mono/VS are a joke on the mac. (They're arguably a joke on PC! :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no londer need UnityVS for the latest Unity version. I can't remember which version UnityVS is no longer requred but I will suggest you try the following below.

1. Uninstall Visual Studio
2. Uninstall Unity
3. Restart Computer.
4. Install the latest Unity version from [here](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta).

Visual Studio should automatically install too. Make sure it is selected during Unity installation.

Don't install UnityVS or anyother plugin. It should work out of the box.